# File iterator in Google Apps script is returning an invalid argument when searching for a file that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to copy mail content with a label (read from a google sheet) into a document with the subject as the doc name. If a doc already exists, I need to add mail body in the same doc, if not, I need to create a doc with the subject as doc name. part of the script that I'm using is this:

```
function searchdrive(x) {
  var iterator = DriveApp.searchFiles(x);

  if(iterator.hasnext()) {  
    var docid = iterator.next().getId();
    return docid;
    Logger.log(docid);
   }
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(x);
  docid = doc.getId();

  return docid;
 }
```

If a doc is not already there, iterator.hasnext() should be returning false but instead it's throwing an error as invalid argument.

How do I work around with this?

Comment: provide your sample 'x' value

Comment: An argument you have passed, it may be invalid

Comment: Hey Nitin, Thanks for the response. I'm not using any special characters. for example, I'm using a string like this: "ZihanLif3"

Answer (score 4):

Googles Apps Scripts utilizes version2 of the Drive API, not v3.

Substitute 'title' for 'name' in your query string.

[v2 Drive API: Search Parameters documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters)

Comment: This is what helped me! When I used 'name contains ...' I got "invalid argument: q" - strange error. But when I wrote 'title contains ...' - it worked!

Answer (score 1):

There are some rules for an argument passed to `DriveApp.searchFiles(params)`
read this documentation   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams

Comment: Hey Nitin, Thanks for the response. I'm not using any special characters. for example, I'm using a string like this: "ZihanLif3"

Comment: Apply debugging strategy and figure out exact issue